# JsonArrayBuilder gives blank output

Tags: java, arrays, json

I've got multiple console logs. The "AB" log in the ArrayBuilder itself gives me the output below which is the correct output. But the log in the input for the ArrayBuilder gives me a blank [ ]. 
Why is the JsonArrayBuilder not returning the correct output?

`"AB[{"ingredientnaam":"Banaan","calorieen":89,"vet":0.9,"verzadigd_vet":0.3,"eiwit":1.2,"koolhydraten":20.4,"vezels":1.9,"zout":0.0}]"`

Input for the ArrayBuilder

```
JsonArray ingredientArray = buildJsonIngredientArray(service.getToday(gebruikersnaam, datum));
System.out.println(ingredientArray.toString());
return ingredientArray.toString();
```

My JsonArrayBuilder

```
private JsonArray buildJsonIngredientArray(List<Dagboek> list) {
    JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();

    for (Dagboek d : list) {
        Ingredient c = d.getIngredient();
        JsonObjectBuilder job = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        job.add("ingredientnaam", c.getIngredientnaam());
        job.add("calorieen", c.getCalorieen());
        job.add("vet", c.getVet());
        job.add("verzadigd_vet", c.getVerzadigd_vet());
        job.add("eiwit", c.getEiwit());
        job.add("koolhydraten", c.getKoolhydraten());
        job.add("vezels", c.getVezels());
        job.add("zout", c.getZout());

        jsonArrayBuilder.add(job);
    }
    System.out.println("AB" + jsonArrayBuilder.build());
    return jsonArrayBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: This seems unlikely, but it might be clearing the internal array after you call `build`. Try storing the return value for build used here: `System.out.println("AB" + jsonArrayBuilder.build());`, and returning it. (full disclosure, no idea if this will work)

Comment: @NeilLocketz What the hell, I don't understand why but it fixed it haha. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem, I'll answer the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be clearing the internal array after you call `build`.
I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation though.

Try storing the return value for build used here:

```
System.out.println("AB" + jsonArrayBuilder.build());
```

and returning it.